# getting error at " edittext.getText().toString() " inside a custom dialog

Tags: android

I am facing errors at the following places inside the custom dialogs that i hav created. Is is not possible to hav such functions inside a custom dialog??

> final EditText x= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtLocationName);
>
> String strTextValue = x.getText().toString();  //here
>
> int x1 =geoLat.intValue()xt().toString();  //and here

Comment: What errors are you facing. Other than the fact that you're trying to assign a String to an int.

Comment: sorry its a misplaced ctrl+c ,for that string to int thing...its actually >int x1 =geoLat.intValue() ...  am getting an error on the onClickListener of the button that does these functions..

Answer (score 1):

you should use

dlgobject.x.getText().toString();

u may use dialog interface to access the contents of a dialog.

Comment: i actually don know how to use the interface... but i literally tried ur idea.. i get a syntax error..

Comment: wat error u got?  Please refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: I think its a limitation in dialogs to use such functions .. I've rewritten it into a activity and it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
String strTextValue = x.getText().toString(); //here
```

^ Nothing seems wrong to me on this

```
int x1 = geoLat.intValue()xt().toString(); //and here
```

^ i think you should try `int x1 = geoLat.intValue(xt).toString();`

Hope that helped :)

Edit: Can you tell what errors you get?

Comment: sorry nt x1 =geoLat.intValue()xt().toString(); was a mistake.. its actually int x1 =geoLat.intValue()